# How to get rid of the "Realm.framework/Realm is not a dylib" warning?

Tags: realm

I am using Realm for our Objective-C iOS app, installed via CocoaPods. However I wasn't able to get rid of the following warning message:

ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/{App_Directory}/Realm.framework/Realm', framework linker option at /{App_Directory}/Realm.framework/Realm is not a dylib

Is there any solution about it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Which version of CocoaPods do you use? Can you share the contents of your Podfile?

Answer (score 0):

Taking another look at that, it seems like you'd somewhere in your project a misconfigured build setting, which contained literally `{App_Directory}`, which won't be substituted as a variable because of the missing leading dollar sign, assuming that you defined yourself `App_Directory` as a build setting. It might be better to just use `$SRCROOT` for that purpose, if that's suitable as well.